# srun: error: Slurm controller not responding, sleeping and retrying

Tags: ssh, error-handling, gpu, redhat, slurm

Running the following command in Slurm:

```
$ srun -J FRD_gpu --partition=gpu --gres=gpu:1 --time=0-02:59:00 --mem=2000 --ntasks=1 --cpus-per-task=1 --pty /bin/bash -i
```

Returns the following error:

```
srun: error: Slurm controller not responding, sleeping and retrying.
```

The Slurm controller seems to be up:

```
$ scontrol ping
Slurmctld(primary) at narvi-install is UP
```

Any idea why and how to resolve this?

```
$ scontrol -V
slurm 18.08.8
```

System info: `gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC)`

```
$ sinfo 
PARTITION AVAIL  TIMELIMIT  NODES  STATE NODELIST
normal       up 7-00:00:00      1 drain* me99
normal       up 7-00:00:00      3  down* me[64-65,97]
normal       up 7-00:00:00      1  drain me89
normal       up 7-00:00:00     23    mix me[55,67,86,88,90-94,96,98,100-101],na[27,41-42,44-45,47-49,51-52]
normal       up 7-00:00:00     84  alloc me[56-63,66,68-74,76-81,83-85,87,95,102,153-158],na[01-26,28-40,43,46,50,53-60]
normal       up 7-00:00:00      3   idle me[82,151-152]
test*        up    4:00:00      1 drain* me99
test*        up    4:00:00      3  down* me[64-65,97]
test*        up    4:00:00      2  drain me[04,89]
test*        up    4:00:00     27    mix me[55,67,86,88,90-94,96,98,100-101,248,260],meg[11-12],na[27,41-42,44-45,47-49,51-52]
test*        up    4:00:00    130  alloc me[56-63,66,68-74,76-81,83-85,87,95,102,153-158,233-247,249-259,261-280],na[01-26,28-40,43,46,50,53-60]
test*        up    4:00:00     14   idle me[01-03,50-54,82,151-152],meg10,nag[01,14]
grid         up 7-00:00:00     10    mix na[27,41-42,44-45,47-49,51-52]
grid         up 7-00:00:00     42  alloc na[01-26,28-32,43,46,50,53-60]
gpu          up 7-00:00:00     15    mix meg[11-12],nag[02-10,12-13,16-17]
gpu          up 7-00:00:00      4   idle meg10,nag[01,11,15]
```

Comment: Talk to your SysOp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are positive the Slurm controller is up and running (for instance `sinfo` command is responding), SSH to the compute node that is allocated to your job and run `scontrol ping` to test connectivity to the master. If it fails, look for firewall rules blocking the connection from the compute node to the master.

Comment: I updated my question based on your comment! what's the command to `ssh` to the allocated job? I am just trying to add the gpu node to my account with `srun` command but I get the error!